# Is there a way to combine all the outputs into one in MS-ACCES?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to make a SQL Filter in MS-Acces where I have the Option to filter all the Elements in the table. But when I make the UNION SELECT, I can show only 1 column in each row, so I made `database_geräte.*` to `database_geräte.ID` . 
This works fine now, but I want all the Outputs from the `database_geräte.ID` select into one row, so that I can Filter all of them at once.

I tried to make a `GROUPCONCAT`, but that gives me an error.

```
SELECT  database_geräte.ID, dbo.GROUPCONCAT (STRINGVALUE)  FROM database_geräte  
UNION 
SELECT database_geräte.Gerät FROM database_geräte;
```

I also tried to make a count on the

```
 database_geräte.ID
```

But then I get the value of the `database_geräte.ID` select, which doesn't fit in the filter because a ID with that number doesn't exist...

The SQL Select:

```
SELECT  database_geräte.ID, dbo.GROUPCONCAT  FROM database_geräte  
UNION 
SELECT database_geräte.Gerät FROM database_geräte;
```

The SQL filter in VBA:

```
sql = "SELECT* FROM database1 WHERE Gerät = '" & Me.GeräteFilter & "'"

Me.sb_1.Form.RecordSource = sql
Me.sb_1.Form.Requery
```

So the Filter should show an option where I can filter all the elements of the table and show it in the subform.

Comment: If you link the subform with the main form via the Master / Child properties this should be automatic? If not maybe edit your post with a picture of what you are trying to achieve , as the description isn't clear to me.

Comment: I solved the Problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made an `UNION` that gives me all the data at once.

The SQL Select:

```
SELECT ID, Gerät FROM database_geräte UNION select "*" as ID, "Alle" as Gerät from database_geräte;
```

Then I made a function, that I can give to two Filters:

```
sql = "SELECT database_geräte.Gerät, database1.Name, database1.Grund, database1.Gerät_ID" _
    & " FROM database_geräte INNER JOIN database1 ON database_geräte.ID = database1.Gerät_ID " _
    & "" & IIf(Me.GeräteFilter <> "*", "Where database1.Gerät_ID = " & Me.GeräteFilter & " ", "") & " " _
    & "" & IIf(Me.Person <> "Alle", IIf(Me.GeräteFilter <> "*", " AND database1.Name = '" & Me.Person & "'", "WHERE database1.Name = '" & Me.Person & "'"), "") & ""

Me.sb_1.Form.RecordSource = sql
Me.sb_1.Form.Requery
```